# Is there a classification of higher-degree generalisations of confocal conic sections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, analytic-geometry

The 1-parameter families of ellipses and hyperbolas with a given pair of points in the plane as their foci yield “orthogonal double-foliations” of the plane.  That is, once the foci are specified, any point in the plane lies on both a unique ellipse and a unique hyperbola, which are orthogonal at the point of intersection.  For a given choice of foci, the family is described by a single polynomial equation in three variables:

$$P(x,y,a)=0$$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis of the conic. When $a$ is greater than half the distance between the foci, the curve is an ellipse, and when it is less, the curve is a hyperbola.

Along with the limiting case of families of parabolas with a given focus and axis of symmetry, there do not seem to be any other 1-parameter families of degree-2 curves with all of the same properties:

- They are defined by a **single polynomial equation** in the coordinates and a single parameter.
- They foliate the plane **twice**, with the two foliations arising from different domains for the parameter.
- The two kinds of curve are **orthogonal** at the point of intersection.

But there must surely be families of curves like this of higher degree.

I’d be grateful for any of the following:

- Specific examples of higher degree families.
- Any classification of higher degree families.
- Relevant terminology that might help with a literature search.